# Workflow error on power automate step of renaming a file

Tags: sharepoint, power-automate

I got this error on the power automate workflow step;

> The expression
> "web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/ESMManila/Shared
> Documents/General/WorkloadPlanning/CurrentWorkPlan.xlsx')/moveto(newurl=concat('/sites/ESMManila/Shared
> Documents/General/WorkloadPlanning/',outputs('Compose'),'WorkPlan','.xlsx'))"
> is not valid.

When i used this uri;

```
_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/ESMManila/Shared%20Documents/General/WorkloadPlanning/CurrentWorkPlan.xlsx')/moveto(newurl=concat('/sites/ESMManila/Shared%20Documents/General/WorkloadPlanning/',outputs('Compose'),'WorkPlan','.xlsx'))
```

When I use it on the Send an HTTP request to Sharepoint flow step for the function of renaming a file appended with the compose formula result.

Comment: Can you show it to us in a screenshot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the expression within the value you could use the @{} formatting around the concat function.

Try this instead:

```
_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('/sites/ESMManila/Shared%20Documents/General/WorkloadPlanning/CurrentWorkPlan.xlsx')/moveto(newurl=@{concat('/sites/ESMManila/Shared%20Documents/General/WorkloadPlanning/',outputs('Compose'),'WorkPlan','.xlsx')})
```

Comment: thank you this works. just modified by adding single quotes outside the concat function

Answer (score 0):

With the help of Expiscornovus. The answer to this question is below;

[image]